# time complexity of contains method in hashtable?

Tags: java, hashtable, contains

I just saw the code of contains method in java.util.Hashtable.java. It has a loop that scans through each entry in the Hashtable and compares it with the argument passed.

I read that contains method takes constant time. How is it possible when it has a loop that scans through each entry.

```
 public synchronized boolean contains(Object value) {
if (value == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}

Entry tab[] = table;
for (int i = tab.length ; i-- > 0 ;) {
    for (Entry<K,V> e = tab[i] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
    if (e.value.equals(value)) {
        return true;
    }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post that part of the code?

Comment: Are you asking about contains or containsKey.  contains checks to see if the map contains a value, which requires checking all entries.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, you should consider HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap if you need it to be thread safe.

Comment: public synchronized boolean contains(Object value) {
 if (value == null) {
     throw new NullPointerException();
 }

 Entry tab[] = table;
 for (int i = tab.length ; i-- > 0 ;) {
     for (Entry<K,V> e = tab[i] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
  if (e.value.equals(value)) {
      return true;
  }
     }
 }
 return false;
    }

Comment: What I would do is calculate the hash of that value ( which would be the bucket) and see if that value exists in that bucket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Hashtable.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) tries to find an entry with an equal *value*. It's lookups by *key* which are constant time (in the usual case) in hash tables.

The docs clarify this:

> Tests if some key maps into the specified value in this hashtable. This operation is more expensive than the containsKey method.
>
> Note that this method is identical in functionality to containsValue, (which is part of the Map interface in the collections framework).

Comment: Fair enough, comment redacted :)

Comment: what is the time complexity for Hashtable.contains() method?

Comment: @user926120: Given that it has to scan through the whole table, O(n)